# Linking scrollbars from 2 different MFC controls

Tags: c++, mfc, scrollbar

I have an MFC dialog with two identical controls - they are both `CGridCtrl` controls. They display the same type of data, only different versions. They are used to identify the differences.

I'd like to link the scrollbars of these controls together, so that when one is scrolled - either vertically or horizontally - both controls will scroll together.

The `CGridCtrl` uses standard MFC scrollbars.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have the window which contains the controls respond to scroll messages `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL`, and use `GetScrollInfo`/`SetScrollInfo` to copy the parameters of one scroll bar to the other.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I couldn't get that to work. The WM_HSCROLL and WM_VSCROLL handlers never got triggered.

Comment: @linusoft, sorry I think I was reading the documentation wrong. It states that the WM_xSCROLL messages are sent to the parent of the control, but that's only for scroll controls themselves not windows containing scrollbars.

Comment: @linusoft, you might be able to see the message if you override `PreTranslateMessage` in your app.

Comment: I have now sorted this issue. For anyone trying to find a solution, I found the following article to be useful:    http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/article.php/c4163/Synchronization-of-scrolling-of-two-list-controls.htm#more